# debugging flash authored content with the flex debugger

Tags: apache-flex, flash, debugging

I am working with a project that is developed in the flash environment, but I love the flex/eclipse debugger in that i can throw a breakpoint in and inspect the vars that are present. Is there a way that I can debug flash in the flex environment?

I have (of course) googled the subject and found that there are several posts on the topic but they are incomplete, missing images, or not working in my environment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, 
thank you, 
-Nathan

Answer (score 0):

I use Monster Debugger: http://demonsterdebugger.com/
This is an excellent tutorial about it: http://gotoandlearn.com/play?id=109 (from Lee Brimelow).
If you hadn't tried it yet, take a loot at it's features. Very good debugging tool.